# Costs of binary operations

Tags: binary, equals, operation

I've ask myself if its cheaper to use `>=` than `==`.
Besides, that `>=` would be more secure in my case, which is a loop, adding objects to a list. The list itself always increase just by one, so a `==` would trigger.

It, for sure, does not affect any serious performance, but I just wanted to know.

Edit:
The language would be Java, but I thought it were kinda universal.

Comment: You're going to have to at least specify what language you're talking about if you want any chance of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for basic types, it wouldn't be any more costly. Essentially they would all call the same compare function, say `C(a, b)`, and process the return -1, 0 or +1. For example `>=` would translate into `C(a, b) != -1`, `==` as `!C(a, b)`, etc.

In some languages though, you can reuse operators, and it might be that `==` vs. `>=` have significantly different costs.

In cases where it doesn't matter between `==` and `>=`, use your personal preference, but keep it consistent. It can be jarring when maintaining code to see inconsistencies like these.